# Как прибавить число к дате?

Tags: python

Есть переменная `a = '2020-12-12'`

Надо к ней прибавить 1 день и получить `2020-12-13`.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 12):

Предлагаю распарсить дату и прибавить к ней [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

***Пример:***

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

a = '2020-12-12'
dt = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d')
result = dt + timedelta(days=1)
print(result.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

***stdout:***

```py
2020-12-13
```

Comment: А можно без каста в конце работать только с датой без времени?

Comment: @dIm0n, совсем без каста наверное нельзя, но можно так:`print(result.date())`

Comment: можно так: `dt = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d').date()`, а дальше работаем с датой...

Comment: @MaxU вот так лучше всего, как по мне

Answer (score 8):

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-12-12', "%Y-%m-%d")
res = date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

print(res.date()) # 2020-12-13
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = '2020-12-12'  
print(a[:-1] + str(int(a[-1]) + 1))
```