# Как получить целое кол-во дней между двумя объектами ‘datetime‘?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime

Есть такая часть кода:

```
dc = datetime.datetime.strptime(dc[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
today = datetime.date.today()
today = str(today)
today = datetime.datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%m-%d')
raz = dc - today
```

Она выводит: `13 days, 0:00:00`

Надо получить кол-во дней, то есть число `13`. Обязательно число должно быть `int`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое сделать?

Comment: `(dc - today).day` ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1166989/398802

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы посмотрите тип вашей переменной `raz`:

```
print(type(raz))
```

То увидите, что это такой класс:

```
datetime.timedelta
```

Можете посмотреть, какие у него есть методы и поля:

```
print(dir(datetime.timedelta))
```

Полей там не так много (сначала там идут методы, я их пропустил для краткости):

```
[..., 'days', 'max', 'microseconds', 'min', 'resolution', 'seconds', 'total_seconds']
```

Вам из них подойдёт поле `days`:

```
print(rez.days)
```